# Finding uncommon elements across multiple vectors

Tags: search, r, vector

I am attempting to find the elements that are not common across multiple vectors. That is, I want to know exactly the elements (not just their position, etc.) that are not shared across all vectors.

The best implementation I could come up with uses a nested-loop, which I realize is probably the least efficient, most notably because the execution is still running as I write this.  Here is what I came up with. (each *.id is a vector of Supreme Court case ID's stored as strings).

```
check.cases<-TRUE

if(check.cases) {
    all.cases<-c(AMKennedy.id,AScalia.id,CThomas.id,DHSouter.id,JGRoberts.id,JPStevens.id,RBGinsburg.id,SAAlito.id,SGBreyer.id)
    bad.cases<-c()
    for(b in all.cases) {
        for(t in all.cases) {
            m<-match(t,b)
            bad<-t[which(is.na(m))]
            bad.cases<-append(bad.cases,bad)
        }
    }
    bad.cases<-unique(bad.cases)
}

print(bad.cases)
```

There must be a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 3):

Trying to find cases where all the Supreme Court justices weren't involved?  Don't suppose that you have a small sample dataset that you could add?

A thought: rbind the vectors on top of each other so that you have a dataset like data.frame("justice","case").  Then use hadley's `reshape` package (use the `cast` function) to sum the number of justices per case.  Any case with less than the total number of justices will be a "bad case".

Comment: ...or just combine them all into one vector (say with `unlist`) and do a count with `table`.